# jqgrid recreateform width setting, only working for edit, not for add

Tags: jquery, forms, jqgrid

Have looked on the jqgrid wiki but cant find what i need.

i have recreateform set to true and setting the width, works fine for edit, but when i try to add a new record the form is not at the width i specify in the recreate form parameters, is their a separate setting for the add form?

here is my code:

```
myGrid = jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid({ 
    url:'data/stokistdata_s_json.php?q=3', 
    datatype: "json",
    mtype: "POST", 
    rowNum:10, 
    rowList:[50,100,150,200,300,400,500,600], 
    pager: '#prowed2', 
    sortname: 'id_mdt', 
    viewrecords: true, 
    gridview:true,
    sortorder: "asc", 
    rowNum:50, 
    scroll: true, 
    editurl: "data/server.php", 
    caption:"Stockist's and Orchid days",
    colNames:[
        'Actions',
        'id',
        'Type', 
        'Name', 
        'Geo Address',
        'Display Address',
        'Telephone',
        'Email', 
        'website', 
        'lat', 
        'lng', 
        'flag', 
        'description', 
        'active'
    ], 
    colModel:[{
        name:'Actions',
        index:'Actions',
        width:100,
        sortable:false,
        search:false
    }, {
        name:'id_mdt',
        index:'id_mdt',
        width:15,
        align:"left",
        sortable:true,
        search:false,
        editable:true,
        hidden: true,
        editrules: { edithidden: false }

        //editoptions:{size:"20"}

    }, {
        name:'id_etp',
        index:'id_etp', 
        width:90, 
        align:"left",
        sortable:true,
        editable:true,
        edittype:"select",
        formatter:'select',
        editoptions:{value:":All;1:Stockist;2:Orchid Day"},
        search:true,
        stype:'select',
        sopt: ['eq'],
        searchoptions:{value:":All;1:Stockist;2:Orchid Day"}
    }, {
        name:'Name_mdt',
        index:'Name_mdt',
        align:"left", 
        width:150,
        editable:true,
        search:true,
        stype:'text',
        sopt:['cn']
    }, {
        name:'geoaddr_mdt',
        index:'geoaddr_mdt',
        width:150, 
        align:"left",
        editable:true,
        search:false,
        edittype:"textarea", 
        editoptions:{rows:"3",cols:"30"}
    }, {
        name:'displayaddr_mdt',
        index:'displayaddr_mdt', 
        width:150, 
        align:"left",
        editable:true,
        search:false,
        edittype:"textarea", 
        editoptions:{rows:"3",cols:"30"}
    }, {
        name:'telephone_mdt',
        index:'telephone_mdt', 
        width:80,
        align:"left",
        editable:true,
        search:false
    }, {
        name:'email_mdt',
        index:'email_mdt', 
        width:80, 
        align:"left",
        sortable:false,
        editable:true,
        search:false
    }, {
        name:'website_mdt',
        index:'website_mdt', 
        width:80, 
        align:"left",
        sortable:false,
        editable:true,
        search:false
    }, {
        name:'lat_mdt',
        index:'lat_mdt', 
        width:40, 
        align:"left",
        sortable:false,
        editable:true,
        search:false
    } , {
        name:'lng_mdt',
        index:'lng_mdt', 
        width:40, 
        align:"left",
        sortable:false,
        editable:true,
        search:false
    }, {
        name:'flag_mdt',
        index:'flag_mdt', 
        width:20, 
        align:"left",
        sortable:true,
        editable:true,
        edittype:"select",
        editoptions: {value:{'1':'Flagged','0':'No Flag'}},
        search:true,//
        stype:'select',
        searchoptions:{value:{'':'All','1':'Flagged','0':'No Flag'}}//{value:":Both;1:Flagged;0:No Flag"}
    }, {
        name:'description_mdt',
        index:'description_mdt', 
        width:150, 
        align:"left",
        sortable:false,
        editable:true,
        search:false,
        edittype:"textarea", 
        editoptions:{rows:"3",cols:"30"}
    }, {
        name:'active_mdt',
        index:'active_mdt', 
        width:20, 
        align:"left",
        sortable:true,
        editable:true,
        edittype:"select",
        editoptions: {value:{'1':'Active','0':'Hidden'}},
        search:true,//
        stype:'select',
        searchoptions:{value:{'':'All','1':'Active','0':'Hidden'}} //{value:":Both;1:Active;0:Hidden"}
    }], search : {
         caption: "Search...",
         Find: "Find",
         Reset: "Reset",
         matchText: " match",
         rulesText: " rules"
   },

    gridComplete: function(){ 
        var ids = jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('getDataIDs'); 
        for(var i=0;i < ids.length;i++){ 
            var cl = ids[i]; 
            be = "<input style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' value='E' alt='Edit Location' onclick=\"jQuery('#rowed2').editGridRow('"+cl+"');\" />"; 
            se = "<input style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' value='S' onclick=\"jQuery('#rowed2').saveRow('"+cl+"');\" />"; 
            ce = "<input style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' value='C' onclick=\"jQuery('#rowed2').restoreRow('"+cl+"');\" />";
            fl = "<input style='height:22px;width:50px;' type='button' value='Find' alt='Find Location' class='findMe' rel='"+cl+"' />";
            gc = "<input style='height:22px;width:50px;' type='button' value='Geo' class='geocodeMe' rel='"+cl+"' />";
            jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('setRowData',ids[i],{Actions:fl+gc}); 
        } 
    }
}); 

jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('navGrid',"#prowed2",
    {edit:true,add:true,del:true,search:true,refresh:true},
    {closeOnEscape:true, recreateForm: true, width:600}
); 
myGrid.jqGrid('filterToolbar',{defaultSearch:'cn',stringResult:true})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misunderstand the meaning of `recreateForm`. I try to explain why it is needed.

The method [navGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3anavigator#definition) has up to 7 parameters. You use only `prmEdit` but not set the `prmAdd` parameter. That is your main problem. The default implementation of "Add" and "Edit" dialog is so that one created dialog will be **not closed**, and only hide instead. Moreover, **one dialog will be shared** (!!!) as "Add" and "Edit" dialog. If `recreateForm` is used that the previously created (and now hidden) dialog will be destroyed and the the new one will be created.

In your case you defined only "Edit" dialog parameters as `{closeOnEscape:true, recreateForm: true, width:600}`. So if the user opens the "Add" dialog **after** the "Edit" dialog the previously hidden "Edit" dialog will be used as "Add" dialog. The title of the dialog will be changed of course.

So you can for example use

```
jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('navGrid',"#prowed2",
    {edit:true,add:true,del:true,search:true,refresh:true},// navGrid options
    {closeOnEscape:true, recreateForm: true, width:600},   // Edit options
    {closeOnEscape:true, recreateForm: true, width:500}    // Add options
);
```

or redefine the grid defaults which are common for both Edit and Add dialog. For example

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.edit, {
    closeAfterAdd: true,
    closeAfterEdit: true,
    jqModal: false,
    recreateForm: true,
    savekey: [true,13]
});
```

Comment: thanks very much that clears it up perfectly, i take it by adding the width:600 under the extend setting this will make all forms 600 wide?

Comment: @Dizzy Bryan High: You are welcome! The setting in `jQuery.jgrid.edit` are common and it will be used by all form of the form editing (all "Add" and "Edit" gialogs).