# jqgrid in local mode with form editing and formatter, wont update the grid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Im using jquery grid in local mode to display some data and in one adtitional field I show the concatenation of 2 other fields that are hidden in the grid but visible in the form edit. When the grid loads for the first time or when I add a new row with form editing the field that has the formatter(concatenation) is shown correctly, but when i edit a row with form editing and try to change any of the field contained in the concatenation, the formatter function is not executed so the field in the grid doesnt show the updated data in the field that has the concatenation.

I have checked then the hidden values and this values are updated, the problem is with the formatter that doesnt update that field. Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you can solve the problem by using [recreateForm: true](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#properties) property of the form edit. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127940/jqgrid-recreateform-width-setting-only-working-for-edit-not-for-add/6128195#6128195) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my problem is not in the form. The problem is when I submit the form, the field with the formatter in my grid is not updated

Comment: @arlievanos: It's difficult to speak about the thing which one don't see. It would be much better if you included the code which shows your implementation. In general the default `reloadAfterSubmit: true` will follows to reloading grid, but probably you changed the option. You can use [afterComplete](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events) to recaclulate the custom field for example.